# How do I ensure a new JDO Entity in Google AppEngine does not exist before creating it?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have a JDO Card entity with an externally generated Key (read from a physical card). This links to a User entity, which is created at the same time as the Card entity. When I read the card and call a method, I want AppEngine to either return me the Card and User previously created, or to create a new one. However, if I call the method twice in rapid succession, I end up with the Card entity being overwritten and two User identities being created.

Here's my code (I've removed getters & setters):

CardEntity.java

```
@PersistenceCapable public class CardEntity {

    @PrimaryKey
    private Key Id;
    @Persistent
    @Unowned
    private UserEntity user;
}
```

UserEntity.java

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class CustomerEntity {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key; 
    @Persistent 
    private String name;
}
```

method from Controller.java

```
    public UserEntity getOrCreateUser(String id) {
        CardEntity cardEntity;
        UserEntity userEntity;
        Query query;

        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        Transaction tx = mgr.currentTransaction();
        boolean complete = false;
        while (!complete) {
            try {
                tx.begin();

                query = mgr.newQuery(CardEntity.class);
                query.setUnique(true);
// rootkey is a key for a CardEntity that I am using as the parent for
// all CardEntities, so they are in the same enitity group, as a hack
// to try to solve this problem.
                Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(rootKey, "CardEntity", id);
                query.setFilter("id == :id");
                cardEntity = (CardEntity) query.execute(key);
                if (CardEntity == null) {
                    cardEntity = new CardEntity();
                    cardEntity.setId(key);
                    userEntity = new UserEntity();
                    mgr.makePersistent(userEntity);
                    nfcCardEntity.setUser(UserEntity);
                    mgr.makePersistent(cardEntity);
                    CardEntity rootCardEntity = 
                                        (CardEntity) mgr.getObjectById(CardEntity.class, rootKey);
                    rootCardEntity.setUser(userEntity);
// this is another hack to ensure that something changes in this transaction
// so that if there's a conflict, it will be rolled back
                    mgr.makePersistent(rootCardEntity);
                } else {
                    userEntity = cardEntity.getUser();
                }
                tx.commit();
            } finally {
                if (tx.isActive()) {
                    tx.rollback();
                } else {
                    complete = true;
                }
            }
        }
        mgr.close();
        return userEntity;
    }
```

I've tried numerous things, but I frequently end up with multiple UserEntities being created. The above code has all the CardEntities in one Entity Group (defined by rootkey), and I've even included a modification on the root Entity as well. This doesn't seem to help.

Any tips, pointers?

Comment: im not sure, because i always use the datastore api directly, but according to docu why you didn't make a getObjectById ?? as described here: 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata#Getting_an_Object_By_Key

this is anyhow the right way to obtain an object by id, dont do a query for that

Comment: Because when it doesn't exist, it raises an exception, which is then more awkward to handle than the query. Also, I don't think this would solve the problem, would it?

Comment: this brings me to the point of your datadesign, throwing a EntityNotFound Exception is usual in java, its a dedicated exception which you can handle inside your transaction, and it will solve your problem, but to come back to design, you maybe should rethink your enitity design, that it could not happen that there is no entity for a given key

Comment: Happy to rethink entity design, but I'm not sure how to create the entity before I know of its existence... The scenario is similar to if I wanted to have an Entity per barcode that someone scanned, and (say) count how many times it was scanned. Given that the barcode space is large, and I don't know which barcodes someone will scan before they do so, I need to create the entity at the time someone first scans that barcode. However, as I am counting scans of said barcode, I can't overwrite the Entity if it's scanned twice. Make sense?

Comment: yes understand it makes sense, 
so in that case i would go fir getObjectById and catch the exception, this totally right todo, and inside catch you create a new entity
the different is, that your query is only eventually consistent where the read is strong consistent, thats behavior of appengine datastore

Comment: Just to clarify what you mean, do you mean that by using getObjectById and a catch, I am actually going to achieve consistency, and not overwrite my object? Do I need this to be within a Transaction as well, or can I just getObjectById and then makePersistent, confident there are no such Objects?

Comment: no, a transaction is to get consistency of different objects, means if you need to insert/update 10 entities, the transaction ensure that either none or all 10 objects are applied, on appengine the transaction does not care about concurrency, but if you do it (checking and creating the entity) in one transaction, the transaction could fail with a ConcurrentModificationException and your second entity will not be created, instead you can make a second get to return the entity in the catch case, By default appengine in java is single threaded,

Comment: the consistency with query and getObject is that, if you create an entity it will be found be getObject directly after creation, where the query at this time may not find it. thats eventual consistency

Comment: Thanks - If you put this in an answer, I'll select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go for: `getObjectById` and catch the exception.

getObjectById have strong consitency wich means, it should immediately return an Object if it is there right after creation.
Where the Query only have eventual consistency, which means it **maybe** found after creation but also maybe not.

in case not found `getObjectById` throws a Entity not found exception which can catch and handle separately.

Comment: This means I need to have a known key for the object, rather than relying on a query. Thanks - back to the drawing board a little :-)